# Why can't I make the data display for the first time login?

Tags: android, android-service, android-sqlite

I'm doing an application.
In the application, I started a service to request the data from a web service, then I inserted the data to the database that is in my device. I query the data from the database and want to display the data to listview.
The **problem** is when I login for the first time, the data can be inserted to the database, but there is nothing in the listview. And I log out and login again, I can see the data in the listview.

How can I make the data display in the listview for the first time login?

There are too many files, I can't post them all. I only can post some of them.
There is the code that is in my fragment:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
            R.layout.infoshare, null);
    contentResolver = this.getActivity().getContentResolver();
    lvshare = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvshare);
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    RunningService runningService = new RunningService();
    runningService.testTopicQuery(params);
    initView();
    return view;
}

    private void initView() {
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Provider.TopicColumns.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);

    List<Map<String, Object>> list = (List<Map<String, Object>>) converCursorToList(cursor);
    TopicAdapter topicAdapter = new TopicAdapter(this.getActivity(), list);
    lvshare.setAdapter(topicAdapter);
}
```

The adapter is coded by myself
And in the RunningService, the code of function is:

```
    public void queryTopic(RequestParams params) {
    final List<Topic> topicList = new ArrayList<Topic>();

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(QYERY_TOPIC, params,
            new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String response) {....}
                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
                        String content) {.....}
```

Comment: post your code or no 1 can help you.

Comment: from your code i see you are trying to `initView()` before you know or -make sure- `runningService.testTopicQuery(params)` have finished, assuming that `runningService.testTopicQuery(params)` is the part where you fetch data from web-service.